# Glassfish 3.1: Cannot find 'View Endpoint' link after deploying a WebService

Tags: web-services, deployment, glassfish-3

I wrote a web service and deployed it on Glassfish 3.1 but I am not able to see the link '**View Endpoint**' link under '**Action**' column. I am using the '**Glassfish 3. 1 Administration Tool**' at '**http://localhost:4848/**' under '**Application**' under '**myapp**'. After getting the web services deployed, I do see the '**webservices**' added under the column '**Engines**'. I need that link for finding '**Web Service Endpoint Information**' so that I could see the WSDL and test the web service using Tester feature given by Glassfish 3.1.

Could someone help me understand whay am i not able to see that '**View Endpoint**' link under the '**Action**' column in the '**General**' section.

Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure why is it happening but I am getting the Endpoint deployed logged and the with the WSDL at hand I am able to access the Web Service as well. But I wonder how come I am not able to see the **View Endpoint** link in the Glassfish 3.1 Administration Tool?

Comment: The client for the web service works fine as well. I just can't understand why am I not able to see that **View Endpoint** link.

Comment: Has anyone found an answer for this issue? I am experiencing this problem in Glassfish 4.1, as well. Tried out the given answers, but none seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

That's how it worked for me:

1. Check if `web.xml` exist in your project (possible it is in `webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml`).
2. Delete `web.xml`.
3. Restart GlassFish server and **"View Endpoint"** link will appear.

Comment: Why does it happen. Can you please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue - when I stopped and restarted the Glassfish server, the "View Endpoint" link appeared.  Not sure if that will work for you, but it did the trick for me.